# Script to add data in the example response

Tags: postman

I want to avoid a manual step of copy pasting a response in the example response section for endpoints that has not been implemented yet. The front end devs need to have some sort of data to get the UI started.

Is there any way we can generate random data based on a provided schema (I already have a schema/contract) using external libraries like (https://github.com/bojand/json-schema-test-data-generator) or any other way in postman ?

Comment: Have you ever tried using this to create the mock of data you need? https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: I'm open to use any mock data generator but the real question is that can I place that data automatically in the example responses without undergoing the manual step of creating mock data and copy and pasting the data manually in example responses ?

Comment: Is there anything in the Postman API that you could use to create a mock? https://docs.api.getpostman.com/

Comment: Yes, we can create a mock from Postman API `https://api.getpostman.com/mocks` but there is nothing about adding an example to an existing mock programatically.

Comment: That sucks - Feature request on their github page maybe?